# How to make a  select query using a local variable in SQLite on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to sqlite and android, my question is simple, in visual studio if you want to make a query from local variable it is done by "'localvariable'" like wise but how on sqlite is possible?

for eg..

```
String local;
local = column1;
```

sqlite query

```
SELECT "'local'" FROM table
```

Table structure

> table: column1 column2

in the above i cannot use the assigned local variable?
what would be the syntax i am not able to figure out.
i use raw query.

any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT ? FROM table", new String[] { local });
```

`?` will be replaced by `local`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String column1 = "NameOfMyFirstColumn";
String column2 = "NameOfMySecondColumn";
String sql = "SELECT "+ column1 +","+ column2 +" FROM table";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```